# how to disjoin child from jfram

Tags: java, jframe

please note to this:

```
public class test extended Jframe implement actionlistener{
test()
{

     Jpanel panel = new Jpqnel;
     Jbutton b = new Jbutton("1");
     b.addactionlistener(this);
     panel.add(b);
     add(panel);
 }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


}
```

I want when i click on `b` button the child that add to Jframe(in this example: `panel`)

disjoint from it.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By disjoin, if you mean remove, try

```
public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel panel;

    test() {

        panel = new JPanel();
        JButton b = new JButton("1");
        b.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(b);
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.remove(panel);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        new test();
    }
}
```